# Not enough distinction between visited links and unvisited in the questions list

Tags: bug, design, user-interface

On the homepage / questions list, the distinction between visited questions and unvisited is incredibly subtle.

At the moment, I can only just see the difference between them, because they are grey and slightly darker grey.

In contrast, [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/) uses blue vs grey, which is much better.